# Shared variables in asynchronous function calls

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, cloud, parse-platform

Is there a basic way to share a variable between two asynchronous functions in Javascript? I'm writing a function for my Parse.com application that sends two queries concurrently and the second waits on the results of the former. I've been using a basic shared boolean and a busy-wait loop, but the loop does not terminate if the boolean value was not set before the start of the loop (but does if it was set before, so the state is in fact being shared across the two callbacks). This makes me think that I need some form of a "volatile" variable but it does not seem that this exists in Javascript, seeing as there are not really threading capabilities/optimizations like this. If it helps, I've added some abbreviated code to help explain what I'm doing:

```
    var firstQueryDone = false;
    var firstResultsError = false;
    var foundUser;
    var foundFollowers;

    ...
    [put some constraints on the query]
    ...

    followersQuery.first({
        success: function(followers) {

            ....

            firstQueryDone = true;
        },
        error: function(error) {
            firstResultsError = true;
            response.error(error);
        }
    });


    .....
    [constraints on new query]
    .....

    commentsQuery.find({
        success: function(comments) {
            while(!firstQueryDone && !firstResultsError);
            if(!firstResultsError) {
                .....
            } else {
                ......
            }
        },
        error: function(error) {
            response.error(error);
        }
    });
```

Comment: You cannot use busy/wait in JS.  As long as one thread of execution is running, no other JS will run and if that thread is waiting for some other activity to complete, it will never get a chance to run and you will have a deadlock (e.g. infinite loop that never completes).  Usually, what you want to do is to trigger the second operation from the completion handler of the first.  Or, if both are running in parallel, you store the data as each finishes and in each completion handler, you check if both are done now.  If you use promises, this is a lot simpler.

Comment: A nice way to store the data is in a closure that both async operations share.  For example, if you start both async operations from a common function, then you can define local variables within that function that the completion handlers for both async operations can access, yet they aren't global and will be GCed when both operations are done.

Comment: Oh that makes much more sense - I had assumed the two could run concurrently. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: JS in a browser is "single threaded" (except for web workers which are not being used here) so two regular pieces of JS never run concurrently.

Comment: Okay awesome. The closure technique worked perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use a busy wait-loop. Instead, have both success and error callbacks call store their state then call an external method that handles.

```
var fComplete = false,
    sComplete = false,
    didError = false;


#.first(
    success: function () {
        fComplete = true;
        checkMethod();
    },
    error: function() {
        fComplete = true;
        didError = true;
        checkMethod();
    }
);
#.second(
    success: function() {
        sComplete = true;
        checkMethod();
    },
    error: function() {
        sComplete = true;
        didError = true;
        checkMethod();
    }
);

function checkMethod() {
    if(fComplete && sComplete) {
        if(didError) {
            //Handle error
        } else {
            //Do success here
        }
    }
}
```

This way, you don't have a wait loop hogging some resources, and you simply have state changes and onStateChange events.

Comment: Not only do you "not have a wait loop hogging some resources", but it won't deadlock and fail to ever complete.  The issue is not one of being wasteful, but rather that a busy/wait loop NEVER works in browser JS because regular JS in a browser is single threaded so as long as one thread of execution is looping, nothing else can ever run.

Comment: @jfriend00 You can specify for an XMLHttpRequest to execute "asynchronously" which would allow this type of behavior.

Comment: Really now? Interesting. I thought the JS "thread" prioritizer would handle it.

Comment: Nope, there is no such thing as a "JS thread prioritizer".  JS is an event driven system.  Events are serviced in a FIFO manner and each event handler runs until it returns as done.  No other event handler can run until the previous one is completely done.  If you loop, waiting for something to change that only can change when another event handler fires, it will never get a chance to run and thus the state will never change.

Answer (score 0):

I think using an object instead of a primitive might help
eg:

```
var firstQueryStatus = {
    qryDone: false,
    qryError: false
};
```